# Batch, How to multiply by percent or by decimal

Tags: batch-file, decimal

I am currently working in batch.
I want to know a way to multiply or add with percents and/or decimals.

Example:

```
set /a wcexpt= %wcexpt% * ??
```

Every time I try this:

```
set /a wcexpt= %wcexpt% * .005
```

it results in a 0.

When I try this:

```
set /a wcexpt= %wcexpt% * %5
```

it results in "missing operand"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simulate operations with decimals using only integer numbers in a very simple way. For example:

```
@echo off

set /P "wcexpt=Enter value: "

rem Get 5% of wcexpt:
set /a percent=wcexpt * 5

rem Show result:
echo The 5%% of %wcexpt% is %percent:~0,-2%.%percent:~-2%
```

Output:

```
C:\> test
Enter value: 1234
The 5% of 1234 is 61.70
```

Of course, a much more detailed simulation that include all arithmetic operations is possible. See [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2704&p=12523&hilit=floating+point#p12523) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that batch uses integers only, so you must convert your formulae to use integers.

Also, the integers are limited to ~ +/- 2**31.

You can extend the range - but it takes some mathematical gymnastics and will be extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it is working it is giving the result as 1

```
set /a wcexpt = 20
set /a wcexpt= (wcexpt * 5)/100
echo %wcexpt%
```

Comment: setting `wcexpt` between 20 and 39 will produce the result `1`, between 40 and 59 will produce `2`, between 60 and 79 will produce `3`, and so on. This is not an accurate method for determining percentages.